# What's the integral of $\frac{1}{x^2}\csc^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

It's known that $\int\csc^2(x)dx = -\cot(x) + C$, but I don't know how to integrate $\int\frac{1}{x^2}\csc^2(\frac{1}{x})dx$. Can you help?
Answer to integral $\int_{2}^b\frac{1}{x^2}\csc^2(\frac{1}{x})dx$ also works.

Answer of this question may give some hints to solution of another question I posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1759629/is-there-a-closed-form-formula-for-sum-k-2n-left-frac-sin-x-sin-fracx).

Comment: See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+csc%5E2(1%2Fx))?

Comment: Thanks for comments! 
I don't know if there's a closed form, and the walframalpha.com link cannot produce result for this integral, so I'm seeking help ...

Comment: @FredYang The new integral is a simple $u$ sub.

Comment: I don't know why wolfram alpha says it has no solution.I can put $\frac {1}{x}$ =$t$ to get the integral.Is there anything wrong in my logic?

Comment: The original question about integral $\csc^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ had no solution on wolfram, but updated question about integral of $\frac{1}{x^2}\csc^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ has a solution now.
Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the term $1/x^2$ is the negative derivative of the function's argument $1/x$. Set $u=1/x$, $du = -1/x^2$. $-du=1/x^2 dx$. The new integral is of $-\csc^2(u)du$. Integrate that to get $cot(u) + C$, and substitute $u$ back into the expression to get $\cot(1/x) + C$.